# Negative Lookahead with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to extract $x but not $$x and '$x'.

1. Read $$x is invalid. Please use $x.
2. You selected '$x' value as $x.

The following Regex works for 1.

```
\$x(?!$)\
```

I used the following Alternation (|) which had obviously failed for the second string.

```
\$x(?!$)|\$x(?!\')\
```

How to check for multiple negative lookaheads?

P.S: Should be compatible with Javascript Regex.

Comment: can you please provide some test input?

Comment: @rockstar These are some test inputs.
1.Read $x books.

2.Read $$x is invalid.

3.Read$x books today.

4.Read books in $xminutes.

5.You selected '$x' as $x.

Comment: so, when $$x is there you want to ignore it or just extract $x part?

Comment: @rockstar should ingore $x when $$x

Comment: What language or tool?

Comment: @revo It is for JavaScript

Comment: Try `(?:^|[^'$])\$x(?!')`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/yiezNC/1

Comment: @revo It is also taking the char before $x which will fail 3 sentence.

Comment: Are you going to replace `$x`?

Comment: @revo yes. I need to replace $x.

Comment: Then use back-reference `'Read$x books today'.replace(/(^|[^'$])\$x(?!')/g, '$1$y')`. This replaces `$x` with `$y`. It could be anything else. The important part is capturing group and using `$1` in replacement string. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/yiezNC/2

Answer (score 1):

The following RegEx should do the trick:

```
(?<!')(?<!\$)\$x(?!')
```

It start by checking there's no `'` at the beginning and not `$` in front of `$x`, finally not ending with `'`.

**Edit for JavaScript**:

```
^\$x(?!')
```

This will select `$x` at the beginning (no `'`) not followed by a `'`.

Comment: But most of the browsers still do not support lookbehinds. Need to use lookaheads only.

Comment: You should mention, that you use javavascript Regex !

Comment: It doesn't match $$x. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: The ^ char checks for a match in the start of the string. Thus, it will not work for any of my test cases provided.

Answer (score 1):

You also can simplify the regex of @revo removing the look ahead :

```
(^|[^'$])\$x([^']?)
```

Replaced by :

```
$1\$y$2
```

[See demo:](https://regex101.com/r/yiezNC/4)

Comment: This works.But the lookahed in the end is more safe for replacement. The first answer you gave requires two back references which can be also be avoided withe lookahead. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I would like to know why it’s safer the look ahead

Comment: Also it’s easier to port to other environments without look ahead support

Comment: I believe that the lookahead is mandatory otherwise `book$x'` will be a match that may not be expected.

Comment: In that case then you proof that my first regex is better, I continue your example with this : **6.Take book$x'$x'.**  or **7. Take book $x'$x'.**   See demo failing : [\[link\]](http://regex101.com/r/yiezNC/7)

Comment: This is not your first regex. It's mine with a negative lookahead.

Comment: Exactly , I put your first version and examples of it failing

Comment: It's not failing actually. You're just putting messed up subject strings there. With or without that trailing optional group in your regex this `$x'` is going to be a match and OP explicitly uses `(?!')` to not match them.

Comment: But your example is going to miss **book$x'$x'** that is totally fine. I understand your points. My example is also going to fail with **book'$x'$x** that is also totally fine.

Comment: I'm not going to guess about OP's requirement. OP is the one who should clear. But in that case I'll recommend `(')\$x(?!')|(^|[^$'])\$x` with `$1$2STRING` as replacement string which cares about`'Book'$x` and similars too. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/yiezNC/9

Comment: Great , better !